# Will mongoose support initializeOrderedBulkOp() which is a new feature in Mongo DB - 2.6

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Am using mongoose - 3.8.8 to connect to Mongo DB. I tried out initializeOrderedBulkOp() - a new feature of MongoDB - 2.6 in mongo Shell and i got proper output. But am not able to do the same with mongoose.
Here is a sample code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB');  
conn.on('error', function callback (err,data) {
    console.log('Error in connecting to DB');
});

var Schema = mongoose.Schema,  
    schema = new Schema({id:Number},{strict:false}),  
    modelObj = conn.model('', schema, 'documents');

var query = modelObj.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
```

Am getting error like

> "modelObj has no method 'initializeOrderedBulkOp"

Any suggestions on this ???

Answer (score 6):

You're really close. You need to drop down a level to the native driver. You can do that like so:

```
var query = modelObj.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
```

From there you can do things like:

```
// queue a doc to be inserted
query.insert({ name: 'Some Name' })

// ... more inserts ...

// execute the bulk operation
query.execute(next)
```

One thing to note though, the un-ordered equivalent, `initializeUnOrderedBulkOp()`, does not seem to exist in version 3.8.9.

Comment: It's throwing me error when i use the below piece of code  "        var bulk = modelObj.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    bulk.insert({ user: "abc123", status: "A", points: 0 });
    bulk.insert({ user: "def123", status: "B", points: 0 });
    bulk.execute(next);"

Comment: Error is "TypeError: Cannot call method 'insert' of undefined"

Comment: Yeah that's really interesting. In the driver I use on my Mac the method exists but I just tried it on Heroku and I get the same error. It would be best to open an issue on the mongoose repo.

Comment: Is there a version with a call back? It fails because the underlying connection has not been established. The typical Node.js flow needs a call back.

Comment: Is there a version with a call back? It fails because the underlying connection has not been established. The typical Node.js flow needs a call back.

Something like: 

```
modelObj.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(function(err, query){
 query.insert(....);
}); 
```